# Ошибка при переписывания программы с Python в C++

Tags: python, c++

Смысл задачи такой, что из числа берутся 2 цифры (1 и последняя) и сравниваются.
Я сам пытался написать на С++, но программа не работает.

Исходная программа на Python:

```py
n = int(input('Число: '))
a = n % 10
while n // 10 != 0:
    n = n // 10

if a == n:
    print('Yes', a)
else:
    print('No'
```

На С++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>
    
int main()
{
    int n, a;
    cin >> n;
    {
        int a = n % 10;
    }
    while (n // 10 != 0)
    {
        n = n // 10;
    }

    if (a == n) {
        cout << "YES, n" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout "No" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: // - это питоновы заморочки :), в С++ просто `/`

Comment: просьба не менять код в вопросе, когда это существенно влияет на ответы. Иначе выглядит как идиотизм какой-то) Вы написали правильный код, вам подсказали о чём-то странном.

Comment: Еще ошибка — объявление `a` в отдельном блоке, внутри которого только она и существует.

Answer (score 1):

В C++ деление двух целых чисел выполняется нацело. как в Питоне `//`.

Для того, чтобы получить деление не нацело, нужно хотя бы один из операндов привести к типу с плавающей точкой:

```
5/4 -> 1

double(5)/4 -> 1.25
```

Так что просто используйте `/`, и устите, что в С++ `//` означает начало однострочного (до конца строки) комментария.